# Identifying 60's vintage PE Ebner amp components: are those capacitors or resistors in the picture?

Tags: capacitor, amplifier, identification

[image]
In the picture there are:
1) 2 brown ones with (silver, black, yellow) bands
2) 2 beige ones with (silver, red, red, red)
3) 2 beige ones with (silver, red, red, orange)
4) 1 beige one with (silver, yellow, red, brown)
5) 2 black ones with (silver, yellow, purple, yellow)
6) 2 small silvery ones with 10?? (and also 25V that cant be seen on the picture) written on them (connected to the triple red silver ones).
7) two yellow caps with 47000pF 10%

What are the 1) - 6) ones? Are they caps? Resistors?

Answer (score 6):

1. They have Brown, black and yellow bands that tell me the value is 100 kohm. The silver denotes the tolerance. Maybe the brown band has become faded over the years and has virtually merged into the background brown colour.
2. Red, red and red denote 2.2 kohm
3. Red, red and orange denote 22 kohm
4. Brown, red and yellow is 120 kohm
5. Yellow, violet and yellow are 470 kohm
6. The small silvery ones look like polystyrene capacitors to me

[image]

The polystyrene capacitors look like this in more detail: -

[image]

This one is coded in value as 682 and means 6800 pF i.e. the "2" represents two trailing zeroes applied after the 68.

Comment: Thanks to you I've identified some other capacitors not in the picture to be polysterine. So here is data about polystyrene capacitors, also called Styroflex caps:
http://www.ebay.com/gds/Color-and-Tolerance-codes-for-polystyrene-capacitors-/10000000021368958/g.html

Answer (score 2):

1-5 are definitely resistors. The color code for resistors was standardized in the 1920's. The 3- and 4-band code was popular before the 5-band code when manufacturing consistency improved and labels to 3 leading significant digits could be given. The brown resistors (#1) are carbon resistors. For #6, I'm thinking those are capacitors. I found [this](http://www.tdpri.com/threads/5e3-vintage-special.451427/) in a forum post on old guitar amps that have some similar looking components. I can't tell the markings on yours from the image, though.